# How to fetch integer value from column having multiple values (comma separated) in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing some issue when I tried to fetch category_id from category column which having multiple values in it. I try to use Like clause but it doesn't work. This is what i tried

```
SELECT * FROM txz43_contact_details WHERE catid LIKE %18%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * 
FROM txz43_contact_details 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('18', catid) > 0
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM txz43_contact_details 
WHERE CONCAT(',', catid, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', '18', ',%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries included*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/308091/1)

Answer (score 3):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM txz43_contact_details 
WHERE find_in_set(18, catid) > 0
```

#### But actually you should really change your DB structure to avoid storing multiple values in one column!

Comment: because `18` is also in `180` or `118`